# Reorder x-axis names based on the alphabetical order of the group that they belong

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","dfgh","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","gh","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)

and I create a heatmap:

library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
HG3 <- split(Gene_states22, Gene_states22$panel)
HG4 <- melt(HG3, id.vars= c("gene_symbol","panel"))
HG4 <- HG4[,-5]

pp <- ggplot(HG4, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
            colour = "grey50") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green", "brown")) +
  labs(title = "Heatmap", x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value") +
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.5, "lines"), ## It was here where you had a 0 for distance between facets. I replaced it by 0.5 .
        strip.placement = "outside")
pp
```

As you will see the names in the x-axis are ordered alphabetically. I would like to re-order them based on the alphabetical order of the group (`panel`) that they belong. So first would be displayed the names that belong to "big" and so on.

Comment: Seems you just need to reset the level of your factor variable, just before you plot. Use this `HG4$gene_symbol = factor(HG4$gene_symbol, levels = unique(HG4$gene_symbol))` just before your `ggplot` chain of commands...

Comment: cool and fast thanks a lot! if you want to add it as an answer I will accept it!

Comment: Also, try to use inside your `theme(...)` function this: `axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)`. Will help you have a better visualisation of the x axis values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small additions to your code (with comments):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

HG3 <- split(Gene_states22, Gene_states22$panel)
HG4 <- melt(HG3, id.vars= c("gene_symbol","panel"))
HG4 <- HG4[,-5]

# reset your factor levels based on how they appear in your dataset and not alphabetically
HG4$gene_symbol = factor(HG4$gene_symbol, levels = unique(HG4$gene_symbol))

pp <- ggplot(HG4, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
            colour = "grey50") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green", "brown")) +
  labs(title = "Heatmap", x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value") +
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.5, "lines"), 
        strip.placement = "outside",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))  # add this to have a better visualisation (uses an angle to avoid overlap of text)
pp
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a numeric grouping variable, which is alphabetically sorted (with `dplyr's` `group_indices`); and then order the x-axis accordingly with `fct_reorder` from the `forcats` package.

```
library(dplyr)  
library(forcats)
```

-

```
pp <- HG4 %>% 
  arrange(panel) %>% 
  mutate(id=group_indices(.,panel)) %>%   #adds numeric group variable; alphabetically sorted
  ggplot(aes(fct_reorder(gene_symbol, as.numeric(id)), variable)) +   #orders x-axis
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
            colour = "grey50") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("white", "red", "blue", "black", "yellow", "green", "brown")) +
  labs(title = "Heatmap", x = "gene_symbol", y = "sample", fill = "value") +
  guides(fill = FALSE)+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.5, "lines"), ## It was here where you had a 0 for distance between facets. I replaced it by 0.5 .
        strip.placement = "outside")
```